# How to generate Anchor CPI from source code?

Tags: anchor, cpi, idl

There are a few libraries to gen the Anchor CPI from IDL file, like [anchor-gen](https://github.com/saber-hq/anchor-gen). They work to some extend, though the output contains some errors that have to be manually fixed. If I have access to the source code of the program is there anyway to generate the CPI file from there?

Edit: I mean, now we can include the source code of said program as a standalone program inside our `/programs` path, and add `lib = { path = "../lib", features = ["cpi"] }` to `Cargo.toml`, but I dont want to include the whole source code there.

Comment: You have the two solutions perfectly! Either you generate the library from the IDL, or you bring in the source code into your project. The Rust compiler is smart enough to drop unused code, so you don't need to worry about bloat from including projects.

Comment: @JonC I followed solution #1 in the end, since the external program had conflicted dependencies that's not trivial to fix. Thank you very much :)